# Android Login Authentication with Retrofit

Tags: android, authentication, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I have a LoginActivity, which gets a username and password.  I'm trying to receive an authentication token using a POST Retrofit 2 and OkHTTP.  I've created the service, which builds the retrofit adapter, as well as the OkHttp client.  I have an interface, but this is where my problems start.

I have to post my credentials(username and password from the login) in a FormEncodedURL to the backend to receive the token, which I have a POJO for called AccessToken.  I'm really not sure I'm doing this correctly with the callback method, etc.

The URL needs to look like 
http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/token/username=smcnary%40metrostudy.com&password=xxxxxx&grant_type=password

Please let me know if there's anything else needed regarding helping me with this post as I'm rather new to android development and stacked.

My POST call looks like this :

```
 @POST("token")
Call<AccessToken> getAuthToken(@Body User user);
```

Where the User model is :

```
public class User {
@SerializedName("password")
String password;
@SerializedName("username")
String email;
String grantType;
public User(String email, String password, String grantType ) {
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.grantType = grantType;
}}
```

And the AccessToken Model is:

```
public class AccessToken {

private String accessToken;
private String tokenType;
private Integer expiresIn;
private String name;
private String title;
private String picImageBase64String;
private String Issued;
private String Expires;
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

public String getAccessToken() {
    return accessToken;
}

public void setAccessToken(String accessToken) {
    this.accessToken = accessToken;
}

public String getTokenType() {
    return tokenType;
}

public void setTokenType(String tokenType) {
    this.tokenType = tokenType;
}

public Integer getExpiresIn() {
    return expiresIn;
}

public void setExpiresIn(Integer expiresIn) {
    this.expiresIn = expiresIn;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getPicImageBase64String() {
    return picImageBase64String;
}

public void setPicImageBase64String(String picImageBase64String) {
    this.picImageBase64String = picImageBase64String;
}

public String getIssued() {
    return Issued;
}

public void setIssued(String Issued) {
    this.Issued = Issued;
}

public String getExpires() {
    return Expires;
}

public void setExpires(String Expires) {
    this.Expires = Expires;
}

public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
    return this.additionalProperties;
}

public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}
```

Here is the logic in the LoginActivity

```
public void login() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Login");

    if (!validate()) {
        onLoginFailed();
        return;
    }

    _loginButton.setEnabled(false);

    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this,
            R.style.AppTheme);
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Authenticating...");
    progressDialog.show();

    String email = _emailText.getText().toString();
    String password = _passwordText.getText().toString();
    String grantType = "grant_type=password";
    User user = new User(email, password, grantType);
    Call<AccessToken> call = figgApiService.getAuthToken(user);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<AccessToken>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<AccessToken> call, Response<AccessToken> response) {
            int statusCode = response.code();
            AccessToken accesstoken = response.body();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<AccessToken> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Just try it, put a breakpoint in your onResponse, and if it never gets there, then it went to onFailure. Why is your URL passing the password like that, you should have it in post data's body

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your interface to this:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("token")
Call<AccessToken> getAuthToken(@Field("username") String username, @Field("password") String password, @Field("grant_type") String grantType);
```

And your call would be like this:

```
Call<AccessToken> call = figgApiService.getAuthToken(email, password, grantType);
```